# How to only append once when loading in html Ajax

Tags: ajax, json, append

I loading in content from a JSON file in a lightbox I have created. The light box opens up another html. In that html I append data loaded in from the JSON file to various elements. However I only want to append once when they open the lightbox, how can I do this?

```
$(document).on('click', '.mch-overlay-info', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#mch-overlay-content').html('');
    $('#mch-overlay').fadeIn(300);
    $('#mch-overlay-content').load(href, function() {
        showInfo(); 
    });
});

function showInfo(){

        $(".start .text3").append(data[lang]['startpage']['text3']);
        $(".start .text4").append(data[lang]['startpage']['text4']);
        $(".start .text5").append(data[lang]['startpage']['text5']);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your problem is that every time they click it appends? Two options:

1. Don't append it. just use `$().html()` to set the content and replace the old content.
2. Control with a variable

   ```
   var hasBeenAppended = false;

   //etc...

   function showInfo(){
       if(!hasBeenAppended) {
           hasBeenAppended = true;
           $(".start .text3").append(data[lang]['startpage']['text3']);
           $(".start .text4").append(data[lang]['startpage']['text4']);
           $(".start .text5").append(data[lang]['startpage']['text5']);
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: thanks boss! Stupid me using append instead of .html, Cheers!